# dynamically load pages using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="menu-items">
    <li class="m-t-30 open" >
        <a href="#" id="dasboard" class="detailed">
            <span class="bg-success icon-thumbnail" style="float:right">
                <i class="pg-home"></i></span>
            <span class="title" >Dashboard</span>
        </a></li>
    <li class="" >
         <a id="messages" href="#">
            <span class="icon-thumbnail" style="float:right"><i class="pg-social"></i></span>
            <span class="title" >Messages</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a list above and want to dynamically load content of a view page.
The file structure looks like,

[image: Directory and File Structure]

Here is the jquery,

```
$(function () {
    $("#dashboard").click(function () {
        $('#content').load("Design/Dashboard");
    });
    $("#messages").click(function () {
        $('#message').load("Design/Messages");
    });

});
```

When I click the link it appends the path with #. For example I am in Dasboard localhost:Design/Dashboard if i click Messages it just adds # like localhost:Design/Dasboard#.

Dashboard.cshtml

```
<div id="content"><h1>Dashboard</h1></div>
```

Messages.cshtml

```
<div id='message'><h1>Message</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple of things and it started working.

```
  <a href="/Design/Dashboard" id="dashboard" class="detailed">
```

In the jquery,

```
$("#dashboard").click(function () {
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method with the click event on the link to prevent the hash from being added to the URL:

```
$("#dashboard").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load("Design/Dashboard");
});
$("#messages").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#message').load("Design/Messages");
});
```

Comment: I tried it.. now the # is not added to the link.. But the page is not navigating..